# Docker - proxy container port on host

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have an Ubuntu VM running on my windows machine (I'm using Vagrant with VirtualBox for that). I am running two docker containers in the VM, one a DB the other a web server.  I want to proxy the web container through the host so that I can browse the web container from the windows machine.

Does docker help with this or do I need something like HAProxy on the VM?

Answer (score 3):

There are differents ways to achieve this.

Lets firt assume you have the following container running on your Docker host:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 tutum/hello-world
```

The [`-p`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) option tells Docker to open port `80` on the Docker host and forward traffic to port `80` of the Docker container.

### By assigning static IP to your Vagrant box

In your *Vagrantfile*, you can assign a fixed IP to your Vagrant box by adding:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "176.16.0.3"
```

Then from Windows, open http://176.16.0.3/

### By forwarding a port in your Vagrant box

If you don't want to assign a fixed IP address to your Vagrant box, you can instead forward port 80 from the Ubuntu box to port 80 of the Vagrant host (the Windows machine).

In your *Vagrantfile*, put

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

Now, from the Windows machine, you can reach the webserver at http://localhost/.

### other considerations

Note that in your Docker container, your webserver MUST accept connections from the outside. In other words you need to bind to the special `0.0.0.0` network interface instead of just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: you actually don't need to go `config.cm.network "forward_port` in vagrant since you have a `private_network` ip; you can just navigate to 176.16.0.3 and access the application on the forwarded port.